# is there any way to get HTTP response code without receiving html files in python?

Tags: python, httprequest, httpresponse

I don't know maybe am asking some kind of weird question or not.

Normally if we use any module in python like requests or urllib3. We get a response for each request. we get status-code, cookies, headers, and the HTML content.

But the problem is! this HTML data is huge and I don't need this data. I just need a response code for a request. So, is there any method or module to do so?

Comment: can you send a HEAD request?

Comment: Oops.  Thank you so much. I totally forgot about that. It will work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
r = requests.head(url)
print(r)
```

Comment: it will return a body which I don't need.

Comment: check again i changed it